# Annotate Type Parameter in Java for Kotlin Compiler

Tags: annotations, kotlin, non-nullable

In Java, I have the following method:

```
public Optional<Foo> getFoo() {
    // always return some non-null value
}
```

In Kotlin code, the return type of this method is given as `Optional<Foo!>!`. By using the `@Nonnull` annotation I can cut this down to `Optional<Foo!>` (i.e. only the `Foo` type is not null-checked anymore).

Is there a way to annotate the method to make the Kotlin compiler null-check the return value correctly?

Comment: As far as I know you can only do this in Java 8+ where annotating generic parameters is allowed

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can do that by annotating the [type use](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/annotations/type_annotations.html) of `Foo` with some of the [nullability annotations that the Kotlin compiler understands](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/java-interop.html#nullability-annotations). Unfortunately, some annotation libraries from the list don't support type use annotation.

I found that `@NotNull` from [`org.jetbrains:annotations:15.0`](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.jetbrains/annotations/15.0) (but not 13.0) has the `TYPE_USE` target, so you can add the library as a dependency to your project and annotate the type use:

```
import org.jetbrains.annotations.NotNull;

...

public @NotNull Optional<@NotNull Foo> getFoo() {
    // always return some non-null value
}
```

Then the return type will be seen as `Optional<Foo>` in Kotlin.

This, of course, can be done with any other nullability annotations from the list I mentioned above that support the `TYPE_USE` target.

Comment: Unfortunately this only works if Kotlin is using the Java source code. Kotlin (currently) does not recognise annotations on type arguments in compiled Java libraries that are used as dependencies.
See https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/java-interop.html#annotating-type-parameters