# @NonNull annotations on definitions- java 8

Tags: java, java-8, annotations, non-nullable

How to use `@NonNull` annotations on `List` items.

let consider, if i want to force **A non-null list of Strings**

This is how we can declare that :  `@NonNull List<String>`

what if we want to force, **A list of non-null Strings.**

**How we can do that ?**

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`@NonNull` Annotation  are from the The **Checker Framework**.

The Framework provides a number of Annotations that could benefit developers to write clean code.

**@NonNull Annotation** – The compiler can determine cases where a code path might receive a null value.

**Java 8 Annotation Improvements :**

Prior to java 8 , annotations were only allowed on definitions.

**Java SE 8 allows type annotations anywhere that a type is used.**

A list of non-null Strings can be difine as `List<@NonNull String>`

*Reference* : [Section 2.1](https://checkerframework.org/manual/#writing-annotations)

Comment: +1, you can find more detailed answer from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45312946/annotate-type-parameter-in-java-for-kotlin-compiler/45313284#45313284).

Comment: @holi-java - Yes, we can use that also.+1 to that answer

Comment: "`@NonNull` Annotation are from the Checker Framework" - maybe, but how do you know, there's [plenty of them](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35892063/which-nonnull-java-annotation-to-use), relevant for this question is only that you choose a variety that is designed for `TYPE_USE`.